# How to change the default format to Total hours: Total minute: Sec in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column which has total machine hours of certain activity. For instance, I have values like followed,

Total Production Time
5:35:55
36:35:09
55:24:45

I couldn't perform any calculation with this column neither import the column into other tools because excel gets this fields has hh: mm: ss AM/PM format. Even if I change to this column into text it gives me some decimal value.

My ultimate aim to calculate total minutes [total hours]*60 + minutes or make this column as it is to import it to my tool where I can achieve the same
I wanted to convert this hour into minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel sees date/time as the number of days since 1/1/1900.  Time is a decimal fraction of a day.

So 12 hours is `0.5`

To get the number of minutes you would multiply by `24` hours and `60` minutes:

```
=A1*24*60
```

This will return the number of minutes.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, this expression works if my cell value is actual hh:mm:ss, my hh:mm:ss is total work hour of machines so some cell value will be like more than actual 24hrs.

Comment: When you say it does not work, what is it doing that is wrong.  If I have a cell with `36:12:00` I get `2172`

Comment: Your expression is correct Scott. I miscalculated your expression. You're awesome !!

Comment: Is there is any way to get the minutes from the cell? I am trying to put this figure in two columns such as hours, minutes like (from your example) 36 & 12

Comment: Hours: `=A1*24` Minutes `=Minute(A1)` seconds `=Second(A1)`  It will return 36,12,0 respectively.

Comment: Thank you!! Scott